# Instantiate is only working sometimes in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, clone, instantiation, projectile

I'm having a bit of an odd issue in a 2d side-scroller game, where unity is only creating my projectile clone sometimes when pressing fire, it removes 1 grenade from the inventory correctly regardless of if the grenade is cloned or not. 
here is my code

```
void ThrowGranade()
{
    if (grenandeInventory > 0)
    {

        GameObject grenade = Instantiate(projectile, projectileSpawnPoint.transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        grenandeInventory =- 1;
        //am.ThrowGrenade();

    }
    else if (grenandeInventory <= 0)
    {
        grenandeInventory = 0;
    }                
}
```

and the fire button script held in the update function

```
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
    {
        if (grenandeInventory>0)
        {
            grenandeInventory -= 1;
            ThrowGranade();
        }

    }
```

i add the force in the start function of the projectile itself

```
void Start () {
    #region REFERENCES
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    am = FindObjectOfType<AudioManager>();
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    player = FindObjectOfType<PlayerScript>();
    capsule = GetComponent<CapsuleCollider2D>();
    #endregion

    rb.AddForce(Vector2.right * player.projectileForce, ForceMode2D.Force);


}
```

Comment: Why are you decrementing your **grenandeInventory** variable twice ? If its value is 1, it will call the **ThrowGranade()** method, but won't instantiate a new grenade. Is that made on purpose ?

Comment: No it wasn't intended that was the second issue I keep passing by in my frustration. Good catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be doing the check in both your throw grenade method and when you click the button before calling the method. The way you set it up right now, if you have 1 grenade, you subtract from the grenade count before calling your throwGrenade so that your throwGrenade sees you have 0 grenades. Just do this.

```
if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
{
        ThrowGranade();
}
```

Your ThrowGranade() Method already handles the logic.

Comment: Ya, I actually just caught that today. I can't believe it took me that long to notice. Thanks for the quick response!